# Correct #if functionality

Tags: c

If I define

```
#if SOMETHING

#endif
```

and I have not defined SOMETHING anywhere. Would the code inside #if compile ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the name used in the argument expression of `#if` is not defined as a macro (after all other macro replacement is finished), it is replaced with `0`. This means that your `#if SOMETHING` will be interpreted as `#if 0`. The code under `#if` will be removed by preprocessor.

The rule applies to more complex expressions as well. You can do

```
#define A 42
#if A + B
```

which will evaluate to `#if 42`, since unknown name `B` is interpreted as `0`

Comment: It is good to cite the C standard when answering technical questions like this: 6.10.1 paragraph 3 says “After all replacements... have been performed, all remaining identifiers are replaced with the pp-number [preprocessor number] 0,...”

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as SOMETHING is also not one of the predfined macros or a macro passed on the commandline to the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think in C99 it defaults to 0 while in C89 it does not as here its giving me an error

```
Source code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A 42
#define B 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int c;

#if A
c = A + B;
#endif

printf("%d\n",c);

return 0;
}

Error : 

error: expected expression before ‘;’ token
```

Comment: That error is about the statement `C = 42 + ;` which you have created with your empty `B` macro. You were pretty close to demonstrating something interesting though: `#if B` would be an error. That's because `B` is defined to the empty string, which makes it different from something that was never defined at all and therefore would be replaced with `0`.

Comment: @AlanCurry `#if B` is an error = `#if with no expression` Perhaps it equates to zero in C99.
I tried without using it as an operand too but i still get error.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said. Confusing verb tense? If it *had* been in the program, it *would have* been an error.

Answer (score -1):

No, because as an undefined macro, it would not necessarily be replaced with anything... but that is probably compiler specifc, and not to be trusted.

You may want to use:

```
 #ifdef DEFINED_WORD
 #ifndef DEFINED_WORD
```

Where DEFINED_WORD is declared by a #define, like:  `#define DEFINED_WORD`. The `ifdef` construct ONLY compiles the code between that and the `#endif` if DEFINED_WORD was defined. The opposite is true of `#ifndef`. You can nest them like so:

```
 #ifdef DEFINED_WORD
 printf ( "DEFINED_WORD is defined\n" );
 #ifndef DEFINED_WORD
 printf ( "This line will NEVER print\n" );
 #endif
 printf ( "This line will print if DEFINED_WORD is defined\n" );
 #endif
 printf ( "This line will ALWAYS print.\n" );
```

In my code, I have constructs like:

```
 #ifdef DEBUG
 printf ( "array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i] );
 #endif
```

To deactivate all of the DEBUG code, just comment out the line that you MUST have before calling that `#ifdef` (top of the source file, or in an included header which you included at the top of the source file, in good form). `#define DEBUG`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Undefined identifiers in #if statements are replaced with 0. This is required by the C standard.

Comment: Well, doesn't hurt readability to use #ifdef.
Although one of these days I should read the C standard. Do you have a link?

Comment: For educational or informal purposes, a draft of the 2011 C standard is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). For engineering purposes, you can purchase a copy of the standard [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853). The first 200 pages (clauses 1-6) contain the core language specification and is quite readable (compared to, say, the C++ standard). Much of the rest is reference material for libraries and extras.